# How to skip authentication in git bash?

Tags: git

After, typing command i.e git push githubRepo master, popup dialog box of github asking to input username and password appear, and when inserting the same github username and password. "LOGON FAILED, CTRL + C to cancel basic credential prompt." appeared with once again popup box of "OpenSHH"asking to enter again username and password for github. Help me please, looking forward for solution plz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+avoid+password+typing

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid typing username and password each time is to put them in to url of remotes.

Assuming you have cloned `https://github.com/krylov123/textru-api` repository, and your `REMOTE` called `origin` (which is default), type:

```
git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/krylov123/textru-api
```

Sure, you need to change USERNAME and PASSWORD to your github credentials.

After that git will not ask for credentials anymore. But be aware, that this method will save your credentials in plane text, totally unsecured.

You can check what `REMOTES` you have, along with the others configurations with that:

```
more ./.git/config
```

Output will be like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://***:***@github.com/krylov123/textru-api
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```